# Quick ways to check in all BluePrinted versions of an item?

Tags: 2011, cme

As an author, I can see the versions of an item using the BluePrint Viewer (by selecting the item then `BluePrint Hierarchy`). I can also see all of (just) my checked out items under tasks. And I believe there was an old PowerTool to also see checked out items as well.

Are there any other CME shortcuts or tips to quickly see the BluePrinted versions of items? A use case would be to prepare these for translation since Translation Manager needs to be able to localize the shared, child (target) versions of translated items.

**Edit**: within a Publication we can also do an advanced search for checked-out items. In summary we can find all checked out items for a given:

- Item (BluePrint viewer)
- User (Shortcuts > My Tasks)
- Organizational item (advanced search)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recently wrote a [blog post](http://www.curlette.com/?p=1095) with code showing how to find all checked out items and then check them in using the Core Service.

I also wrote a small VBScript app that finds the localized copies and then copies them to another item, called [BCopy here](http://www.curlette.com/?p=236)

I hope this gives you some nice code examples of how to do it.

Comment: +1 and accepted. If you've written a script, then I think this covers the out-of-the-box features as well as examples for the core service part of an extension, thanks. We can also add a use case to PowerTools 2011 to see if anyone else would be interested in some kind of "power check-in" extension.